# Firebase Cloud Firestore Composite Index NO query results

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app on Flutter with Firebase, I've successfully added Firestore and everything works now.

```
getUsers() async {
    final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await usersRef
        .where("postsCount", isLessThan: 3)
//        .where("username", isEqualTo: "Parzival")
        .getDocuments();

    snapshot.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      print(doc.data);
      print(doc.documentID);
      print(doc.exists);
    });
```

When I run the above cell with **the second commented** it works !

I want to run a composite query so in the terminal i followed the link google gives to create an Index.

When I manually create an Index there with the the correct fields and successfully enable it,
Then I uncomment my line and run it, **The terminal shows no error but it also doesn't print the information it was supposed to give.**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the composite index section for the project?

Comment: I didn't get you, can you elaborate ? Do you mean my code or the image of my index on firebase console ?

Comment: I've added it on the post. You can check it out

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you explain what you mean ? Note: The `usersRef` is referenced earlier in my dart file as `final usersRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access array index of Cloud Firestore using query in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180156/how-to-access-array-index-of-cloud-firestore-using-query-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I think question is related with another made it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180156/how-to-access-array-index-of-cloud-firestore-using-query-in-flutter), however I recommend you take a look at this [document](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40) where you can find useful examples about how to do queries using fluttler.

You could improve your query on this way:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await sl.get<FirebaseAPI>().getFirestore()
        .collection('usersRef')
        .where("postsCount", isLessThan: 3)
        .where("username", isEqualTo: "Parzival")
        .getDocuments();
```

Finally I recommend you check this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I'll check it out and let you know. Sorry I don't ask much questions here, I'm not familiar with the custom yet.